# Numbering section and chapter as Munkres

Tags: sectioning, numbering, book-class

How can I make chapter and section numbering as

Chapter 1
Section 1
Section 2
Chapter 2
Section 3
Section 4

without using \setcounter command at each chapter?

Comment: Writing in the preamble `\counterwithout{section}{chapter}` should do it, but this may depend on your document class.

Comment: Thankyou for answering the question.

Comment: The problem has solved! Thank you :)